# External/global variable in C

Tags: c

I am learning about global variables in C using book C programming a modern approach.

Below is given an example from the book why using same global variable for multiple functions is bad idea.
I don't understand why function `print_all_rows` executes function `print_one_row` only once.

Let's say I call first function `print_one_row` and then function `print_all_rows`.
At the beginning of program `i` is set to 0 by default by compiler. Once program finishes execution of `print_one_row` function the value of `i` is 11.

Program enters into function `print_all_rows`, sets `i` to 1, calls function `print_one_row` and then **increments `i` to 12 instead of 2**.

Why is it incrementing `i` to 12 and not to 2 if I changed the value of `i` to 1?

```
int i;
void print_one_row(void)
{
    
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        printf ("*" ) ;
}
void print_all_rows(void) {
    
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        print_one_row();
        printf ("\n") ;
    }
}
```

Comment: At the start of `print_all_rows` it is set to 1, but then `print_all_rows` calls `print_one_row` which sets it to 11. Therefore it is 11 by the time it reaches the `i++` for the second iteration in `print_all_rows`.

Comment: What is the value of `i` after you call `print_one_row()`?

Comment: The variable `i` in both loops is the same. So the second loop is incrementing the variable that's being used to control the first loop.

Comment: It's not clear whether you realize this, but the behavior you are asking about is exactly what the book is trying to show you, as a simple, somewhat contrived example of its assertion that "global" variables should be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `print_all_rows`, just before the first call to `print_one_row`, `i` has the value of 1.

Then `print_one_row` is called.  When that function returns, `i` has the value of 11.  Then the loop increment in `print_all_rows` is evaluated which increments `i` from 11 to 12, then the condition is evaluated which is false, then `print_all_rows` returns.

Answer (score 2):

Because `i` is glocal variable (common for both functions) and its value is `11` after first call of `print_one_row`. With this value (11) the second iteration of `for` loop in `print_all_rows` exits and there are no more calls of `print_one_row`.